# Multiplying with plus or minus sign in front

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time following what happens in between these steps:

$\frac{L^2}{(1{\mp}e)}=L^2(1{\pm}e)$

How did the minus-plus sign move to the numerator after a change to a plus-minus sign?

Comment: $\dfrac 1 {1-x} = 1 +x +  x^2 + x^3 + ...$

Comment: $\dfrac1{1\mp e} = \dfrac1{1\mp e}\cdot\dfrac{1\pm e}{1\pm e} = \dfrac{1\pm e}{1-e^2}$

Comment: Your equation is incorrect, unless $e=0$ or $L=0$. Are you sure you have it right?

Comment: Your equation is shorthand for the pair of equations, $L^2/(1+e)=L^2(1-e)$ and $L^2/(1-e)=L^2(1+e)$. These equations are easily seen to be correct (provided $e^2=0$).

Comment: Any thoughts on all these comments, Bob?

Comment: I emailed my professor as well, and he told me to consider a Taylor Series expansion. However, I am not too sure why we could ignore the rest of the terms.

Comment: Is $e\ll1$ (much less than $1$)?

Comment: This is actually my physics problem, I was just stuck on the math bit. The L is the angular momentum of a planet orbiting a larger mass and the e is the eccentricity of the orbit. We are not given any actual numbers, so I'm not too sure if the eccentricity is much less than 1.

Comment: Planetary orbits generally have small eccentricity (especially now that Pluto's gone).

Comment: Oh okay! That makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much everyone!